# pyinstaller cannot use tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm trying to get an otherwise working Python program to freeze to a single-file executable file using pyinstaller, but I keep running into the same error related to pyinstaller. I have reduced to program to the absolute minimum to provoke the error, ie. importing tkinter.

Test program:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Terminal command:

```
pyinstaller --clean --hidden-import tkinter test.py
```

Output:

```
1625 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753
1625 INFO: Python: 3.6.3
1647 INFO: Platform: Darwin-17.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
1648 INFO: wrote /Users/jacob/test/test.spec
1653 INFO: UPX is not available.
1654 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in /Users/jacob/Library/Application Support/pyinstaller
1655 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/jacob/test', '/Users/jacob/test']
1656 INFO: checking Analysis
1656 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
1656 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1658 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
1666 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5415 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tkinter'
5568 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
5595 INFO: Caching module hooks...
5600 INFO: Analyzing /Users/jacob/test/test.py
5604 INFO: Loading module hooks...
5604 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
5623 INFO: checking Tree
5624 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
5624 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
5704 INFO: checking Tree
5704 INFO: Building Tree because out01-Tree.toc is non existent
5704 INFO: Building Tree out01-Tree.toc
5746 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
5840 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
6143 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
6157 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
6157 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
6159 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
6168 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
6453 INFO: Looking for eggs
6453 INFO: Using Python library /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
6456 INFO: Warnings written to /Users/jacob/test/build/test/warntest.txt
6483 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /Users/jacob/test/build/test/xref-test.html
6507 INFO: checking PYZ
6507 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
6508 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/jacob/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz
6846 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/jacob/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
6851 INFO: checking PKG
6851 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
6851 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
6874 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
6877 INFO: Bootloader /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/run
6877 INFO: checking EXE
6877 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
6877 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
6883 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /Users/jacob/test/build/test/test
6888 INFO: Fixing EXE for code signing /Users/jacob/test/build/test/test
6894 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
6897 INFO: checking COLLECT
6897 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
6897 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
7923 WARNING: failed to copy flags of /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/msgs/da.msg
7925 WARNING: failed to copy flags of /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/msgs/lv.msg
7927 WARNING: failed to copy flags of /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/msgs/kl.msg
7928 WARNING: failed to copy flags of /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/comdlg.tcl
7930 WARNING: failed to copy flags of /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/msgs/gv_gb.msg
7932 WARNING: failed to copy flags of /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/text.tcl

     <snipped 298 very similar lines>

8423 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

On running the executable:

```
Last login: Sun Dec 17 09:39:40 on ttys001
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:~ jacob$ /Users/jacob/test/dist/test/test ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jacob/test/dist/test/_tkinter.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/Tcl
  Referenced from: /Users/jacob/test/dist/test/_tkinter.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /Users/jacob/test/dist/test/Tcl: not a file
  /Users/jacob/test/dist/test/Tcl: stat() failed with errno=25
  /Users/jacob/test/dist/test/Tcl: not a file
  /Users/jacob/test/dist/test/Tcl: stat() failed with errno=25
[731] Failed to execute script test
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

How do I get an otherwise working Python program, using tkinter, to freeze to a single-file executable file using pyinstaller?

**Update:** Updated output and runtime error, since I had ended up with a different error than I wanted to ask about.

Comment: first `File exists: '/Users/jacob/test/dist/test'` means that you already have this file and maybe you have to delete it before you run it.

Comment: Whoops. That was not actually the problem I'm having, but must have happened in the process of getting the output for posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is related to the path of Tcl/Tk on macOS. I found a workaround which involved compiling my own version of Pyinstaller, fixing the error, but breaking Pyinstaller for everything except macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with Python 2.7. I worked around it by installing `py27-pyinstaller` from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=py27-pyinstaller).